# Data manipulation in nested json file with multiple objects

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I have this subset of my JSON file "json" in R

```
library(jsonlite)
json <- '{"year": {"2015":{"id": 10, "number": 1, "amount": 5},"2016": {"id": 2, "number": 6, "amount": 9}}}'
data1 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)
v<-as.data.frame(data1)
v
```

Which look like this

```
  year.2015.id year.2015.number year.2015.amount year.2016.id year.2016.number year.2016.amount
1           10                1                5            2                6                9
```

But i only want the last object which has the variables "id", "number", "amount". 
So the wanted output would be like this.

```
id  number amount
10  1    5
2   6    9
```

How do i achieve this when the json file is nested and i only want to look at the level, where the data has variable id year and number and not at the level with year.

Best Regards, 
Christian Skjøth

Comment: Would it work to just manually call the `year` sub-part? `data.frame(do.call(Map, c(c, data1$year)))` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`library(jqr)`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jqr/index.html) to subset the json itself, then build the data.frame after you've extracted the values you want

```
jqr::jq( json, '.[][]') %>%
  jqr::combine() %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON()

#   id number amount
# 1 10      1      5
# 2  2      6      9
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens when you convert the list of list of dataframe automatically into a dataframe, what you need is to access list of dataframe data1$year instead of data1 and then binding the data.

#### Preparing the data

```
library(jsonlite)

json <- 
  '{"year": {"2015":{"id": 10, "number": 1, "amount": 5},"2016": {"id": 2, "number": 6, "amount": 9}}}'

data1 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)
```

#### Binding method 1

```
do.call("rbind", data1$year)
# id number amount
# 2015 10 1      5     
# 2016 2  6      9
```

#### Binding method 2 using dplyr

```
dplyr::bind_rows(data1$year, .id = NULL)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# id number amount
# <int>  <int>  <int>
# 10      1      5
# 2      6      9
```

#### Binding method 3 using plyr

```
plyr::ldply(data1$year, data.frame, .id = NULL)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# id number amount
# <int>  <int>  <int>
# 10      1      5
# 2      6      9
```

Comment: Note that these methods don't give the same results. The base `rbind` method gives a list of length 6 folded into a matrix. `bind_rows` on the other hand gives a `tibble`/`data.frame` with 3 columns.